# Using vomiting in a sentence

Tags: grammar

why it's grammatically incorrect to use this sentence

**“I am feeling vomiting"**

I know this sentence is wrong but i don't the reason.

Comment: In US English (not so much in ***UK*** English), you could use adjectival / adverbial ***vomitous*** here. Most Brits would duck the issue and say ***sick*** (even ***nauseous** = liable to vomit* strikes me as primarily a US usage).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I thought "vomitous" refers to something that makes you want to *vomit*? Synonymous with "nauseating".

Comment: I'm with Andrew; MW defines *vomitous* circularly as something *vomitive*. I tend to say I feel *queasy* to avoid getting into arguments about the distinction between *nauseous* (causing nausea) and *nauseated* (feeling nausea). *Sick* is also used in AmE, with sufficient context of course: *sick from the mayonnaise* is different from *sick from being out in the rain*, leading to peculiar statements like *the cancer treatment was going well, except the medication made her sick*.

Comment: @Andrew, choster: Checking the full OED, I see you guys are quite right. Their definition *(**repugnant, loathsome, nauseating**)* obviously leans more towards the "figurative" sense. But they also say it's a ***US usage***, which is my excuse for why I didn't know about that fine point.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can't recall seeing it any other way than *nauseating* eg *"A **vomitous** meal of black pudding, kidney pie, and haggis. "* :)

Answer (score 4):

"Vomiting" is an action verb. Consider the words walking or running or flying. You also cannot say "I am feeling walking."

To say you feel something requires a word that indicates something you can feel. You might say "I feel like I am going to vomit." Or you might say "I am feeling like I need to vomit." Or you might say "I feel like I did yesterday just after vomiting." (Or just before, possibly.)

Or you could use various related words. "I am feeling nauseated." This means you are feeling that your stomach is upset and that you might vomit.